Issue with training Keras model using ModelCheckpoint in Kaggle notebook (Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs))
I'm encountering an issue while trying to train a Keras model in a Kaggle notebook using TensorFlow's ModelCheckpoint callback. Here's my setup and the error I'm facing:
Setup:
I'm building a Keras model for multi-label classification using TensorFlow. Here are the relevant parts of my code:
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import AdamW

epochs = 4
loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
classifier_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                         loss=loss,
                         metrics = 'roc-auc')

print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
checkpoint_filepath = '/kaggle/working/tmp_weights.h5'

model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    save_best_only=True)

history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_ds,
                               validation_data=val_ds,
                               epochs=epochs,
                               callbacks = [model_checkpoint_callback])

Error:
Upon running the training script, I encounter the following error:
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). This could be due to issues in input pipeline that resulted in an empty dataset. Otherwise, please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

Additional Context:

I'm using a TensorFlow Hub encoder (tfhub_handle_encoder) for text embeddings.
train_ds and val_ds are objects containing my training and validation data, respectively, and they are of this format: <_TakeDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 6), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
I've verified that my data loading and preprocessing steps are correct and that train_ds and val_ds are not empty.

Request:
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue with the ModelCheckpoint callback in my Keras training script on Kaggle. Thank you!

Check that your metrics and optimizers are contained within a list, as Keras wants them as such. Plus, it wants a ROC metric, as far as documentation goes.
loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
classifier_model.compile(optimizer=['adam'],
                         loss=loss,
                         metrics = ['ROC'])

